# Empty item in Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have problem with Owl carousel. I have 10 items in owl, in loop, and after 10th item, there's one extra blank item. How can I get rid of that blank item?

Here is my js code for owl:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({

            navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
            pagination : false,
            loop : true,
            autoplay : false,
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            items : 1 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you found solution for that? i have the same issue.

Comment: same issue. none of the answers below worked

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem. After some research and trial, I found that removing all whitespace in my HTML solved the issue.

Comment: Definitely white space if <p> tags are being generated in WP

Comment: Very useful. just minified your html and render again.

Answer (score 1):

Check if css files are added

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had try this one and solve my issues.

```
#ba.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set **loop: false** and it should solve it!
Also, if you need that to loop, add **rewind: true** to the carousel object.

Comment: Didn't worked for me mate the blank is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem . I fixed it by changing the position of following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('#banner');  
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
  }); 
});
```

Initially this script was inside of the main owl carousel `div` (the outer `div` with the classes `.owl-carousel` and `.owl-theme`) .

Now i moved it to out side of that `div` . Currently it executes after the above mentioned `div`.
It worked and the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Check the empty item by inspect element. Probably it contains unexpected HTML. In my case, it was some other element from somewhere in the page, that end tag was missing matching start tag.

Answer (score 0):

the element with .owl-carousel class should be only the the parent of carousel items. put other elements (except carousel items) out of .owl-carousel .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.owl-carousel.owl-loading{opacity:1;}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.